# Restrict user to input y or n and show result accordingly in C#

Tags: c#, loops, boolean-logic

I am writing a code that asks the user for his name, and if he wants to read a joke. The answer should be limited to y or n. Any other character should be considered invalid and should loop back to the question. Here's what I've done so far.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name="";
        string KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello, what is your name?");
        name=Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Greetings, " + name + ". Would you like to read a joke? (y/n)");

        ConsoleKeyInfo result = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        while (true)
        {

            while ((result.KeyChar != 'Y') || (result.KeyChar != 'y') || (result.KeyChar != 'N') || (result.KeyChar != 'n'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid key. Limit your answer to y or n");
                break;
            }

            while ((result.KeyChar == 'Y') || (result.KeyChar == 'y') || (result.KeyChar == 'N') || (result.KeyChar == 'n'))
            {
                if ((result.KeyChar == 'Y') || (result.KeyChar == 'y'))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Joke question?");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Joke answer.");
                    break;
                }
                else if ((result.KeyChar == 'N') || (result.KeyChar == 'n'))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You're missing on all the fun! Suit yourself. Goodbye!");
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: result = Console.ReadKey(); at the end of while(true) and replace your 2 inner whiles with ifs.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off writing a separate method to ask for a Y or N, for example:

```
public static char YorN(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt + " ");

    while (true)
    {
        char input = char.ToUpper(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);

        if (input == 'Y' || input == 'N')
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            return input;
        }

        Console.Write("\b \b"); // Use backspace ('\b') to erase the incorrect character.
    }
}
```

Then you wouldn't need to call it in a loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, what is your name?");
string name = Console.ReadLine();

char response = YorN("Greetings, " + name + ". Would you like to read a joke? (y/n)");

if (response == 'Y')
{
    Console.WriteLine("Joke question?");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Joke answer.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're missing on all the fun! Suit yourself. Goodbye!");
}
```